# What is the origin of the spin selection rule?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, spin

Why is the change in total spin ∆S = 0 during an absorption of a photon, in contrast to the ∆L = ±1, where the photon transfers its angular momentum?

I am aware that spin-orbit coupling breaks this, I want to know why its a rule in the first place.

Comment: Photons have one unit of angular momentum only ($S= 1$), and on absorption or emission the angular momentum of the atom or molecule+photon is always conserved. For example singlet to triplet transfers occur but only if angular momentum from elsewhere (other than spin) is used, as in your example of spin-orbit coupling.

Comment: Thanks @porphyrin Do photons also have orbital angular momentum %l = 1%?  If they do, why does transferring this to the molecule not change their orbital angular momentum to 0?  If they don't, how can absorption of a photon cause a change the orbital angular momentum of the molecule?

Comment: yes photons have angular momentum, quantum numbers $S=1, m_s=\pm 1$  and yes it changes the angular momentum of the molecule so that the total in the molecule plus photon is the same as in the  excited molecule after the photon is destroyed by being absorbed. The angular momentum of the atom/molecule is changed by $\pm 1$ unit from whatever it was before. You see this clearly in a vibrational-rotational spectrum such as from HCl, where  only $J$ changes by $\pm 1$ are observed and $J'=0 \to J''=0$ is not observed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused.  You're saying photons have $S = 1$ (spin angular momentum), the change in spin orbital angular momentum is usually 0 during the absorption of a photon.  Do they have orbital $L = 1$ as well as  $S$ in order to get $\Delta L = 0$?   If they can freely re-allocate angular momentum between $L$ and $S$ to get the general change in $J$, then why is $\Delta S$ required to be 0?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it is quite simple in outline. Photons have 1 unit of  angular momentum, however, the electron *spin* is not affected by this but in a dipole transition the atom/molecule orbital angular momentum has therefore to change by 1 unit, i.e. orbitals $s \to p,\; p \to d$ etc for a dipole transition. Similarly in molecules but now you need to look at the point group to determine which symmetries are involved.

Comment: So if angular momentum is being transferred from the photon to the electron, but it does not affect the spin of the electron, does that mean that the photon's angular momentum is not spin angular momentum $S$, but orbital angular momentum $L$?

Comment: Well, its easier to think of the angular momentum of an orbital and so not get confused with electron spin's angular momentum. The photon has angular momentum, thats it, (not spin or orbital, just ang. mom. ) and this is transferred to the atom/molecule's orbital angular momentum so that overall ang. mom. is conserved.

Comment: This would make sense, however I have been reading recently (and I do not fully understand the explanations) about light carrying both spin and orbital angular momentum.  My limited understanding is that spin is rotation of polarisation vector (like what we use to measure chirality), while orbital is related to helicity of wavefronts.  Wikipedia has formulae, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light
but I still do not understand the $\vec{A}$ field, so they don't make sense to me.

Comment: What I get out of it, is that they are two properties, light can have both, and they're not the same.  I think spin is carried by all light (what if it's linearly polarised?) so I don't understand why spin angular momentum of photons turns into orbital of molecules.  Maybe angular momentum is angular momentum, and it doesn't matter where it comes from.  But if that's the case, then the selection rules wouldn't be that the transfer of angular momentum from photons can Only change molecular $L$, and must change $L$, and not $S$.  Right?

Comment: The electron's spin is separate from its orbital angular momentum, also sometimes also called 'spin'.  The true electron spin was discovered with the anomalous Zeeman effect and the Stern-Gerlach experiment. But the electron is a structureless elementary particle of no measurable size so its best to think of it having property which has equations that have the  same form as angular momentum. V. odd I know.

Comment: continued...The electron 'orbital angular momentum' is what is used in transitions as is its polarisation in electric dipole transitions. The integral $\int \psi_i\,\mu\,\psi_fd\tau$ has to be evaluated. $\mu$ is translation operator, $x,y,z$ in the point group, and $\psi$ the wavefunctions. This has to be non-zero if a transition is allowed. A really good text is 'Atomic Physics' by CJ Foot (publ. OUP) p35.

Comment: Are you saying that whatever type of angular momentum the photons have, $S$ or $L$, when they interact with an electron, because the interaction involves electron polarisation and the dipole operator this turns into $\Delta L$ for the electron?

Comment: effectively yes, the photon does not change the electron spin quantum number